# How to setup IKEv2/IPSec MSCHAPv2 VPN on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, vpn, android, windows-server, windows-server-2019

The google appreantly removed other VPN options such as PPTP from VPN setup. With PPTP there are tons of easy guide to setup your VPN on Windows Server.

However, I can't find a single guide for how to setup a VPN server that Android 12 Phone can connect

Here my Android 12 phone only available VPN connection (Poco X3 Pro)

So I need help / guide to setup a VPN on my Windows Server 2019 that I can connect with my phone

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing intensive research, I have found a way to make it work.

I have used open source VPN service SoftEther  and another free software service OpenVPN.

I made a very detailed tutorial video for those who is interested in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jzmXwZgx5U

Comment: For those trying to avoid third party software on their phones, this will not work!